# JS animation only effects one element and it barely works

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm trying to make an animation for my dropdown mega menu and I came up to a problem where it only works when I hover over customizer buttom, slowly. I can't figure out why. Can someone more experienced with JavaScript help me?
Here's my JavaScript code, full code (html,scss) can be found [here](https://codepen.io/Arconi/pen/bGoXKzp) (codepen link):

```
const button = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
button.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  document
    .querySelector(".dropdown-content")
    .classList.toggle("scale-up-ver-top");
});
```

Comment: What do you expect it to work? You want it to work for every button?

Comment: Please add your code here as a [mre], and not as a link to an external site - 3rd party links tend to change/break over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you could do to make it works.

First, `document.querySelector()` only return a single element, which answers why only the customizer button works. To fix this, you need to use `document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown")`.

Second, inside the event listener, I understand that you want to select the `".dropdown-content"` of the dropdown that is being hovered. But `document.querySelector(".dropdown-content")` will just simply select all the dropdown content in the DOM. To fix this, you need to replace `document` with the current dropdown element.

Here is the full script I've re-written from your codepen:

```
// select all dropdown buttons
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

// loop through each button
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("mouseenter", e => {

    // e.target => the one that you're hovering
    e.target
      .querySelector(".dropdown-content")
      .classList.toggle("scale-up-ver-top");
  });
});
```

Check it out at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/phucbui/pen/OJxKEKM), I also added a mouseleave event.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector(".dropdown")` only returns the first element found with the `dropdown` class. You need `querySelectorAll`, and then you need to loop through all of the elements and add a mousenter listener to each one.

Comment: his issue is not with displaying the function to all buttons, his problem with the animation

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

If  you refer to you have to toggle two times then, it works, it because you set the `classList.toggle` which means at first time, it will add the `"scale-up-ver-top"` class to the element and second time it will find the old `"scale-up-ver-top"` and it will remove it a possible solution is to add `(toggle, true)` which means it will only add class to the element.

```
const button = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
button.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
document
    .querySelector(".dropdown-content")
    .classList.toggle("scale-up-ver-top", true);
```

If you are refers to the problem, you want to assign all the buttons, use:

```
const button = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
button.forEach(item =>{
item.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
document
    .querySelector(".dropdown-content")
    .classList.toggle("scale-up-ver-top");
  document
    .querySelector(".dropdown-content")
    .classList.toggle("scale-up-ver-top");
});
})
```

Comment: the second function is just like times one in math, it doesn't do anything. he only needs to delete the JS and add the function manually in HTML as I've said in my answer...

Comment: @Sarout I suppose you could, but then again, there are a million ways of solving issues when it comes to these things.

Answer (score -1):

if you realize it, you have to go 2 times so the class toggled, I think this class should be only while hovering, doesn't it?

so remove the js, and add `scale-up-ver-top` to `.dropdown-content` directly in HTML

**EDIT**
for `mouseenter` add this function so it removes the class when the mouse leaves the element, so it'll be like:

```
const button = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
button.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  document
    .querySelector(".dropdown-content")
    .classList.toggle("scale-up-ver-top");
});
button.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
  document
    .querySelector(".dropdown-content")
    .classList.toggle("scale-up-ver-top");
});
```

Comment: I am not the person who downvote you but I have to say hover is completely different from mousenter and in term of your comment to my answer, the op has stated that op is asking for why JS animation only effects one element and it barely works

Comment: oh sorry for this, but I tried to solve it basically, I'll make it in mouseenter

Comment: But you are giving the same code what the user has already do. Also toggle will not working as my answer stated that it will remove the class every two times

Comment: I said add the code not replace it with, please focus

Comment: anyway I added how the full code should be like

Comment: I tried adding the animation directly into HTML and since I couldn't get it to work at all I went with JS and had small success. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ahh man, don't worry, it's totally fine I only want to practice and help. Thank you for your appreciate